# parse gz file in aws s3 using python

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I am trying to bulk copy tables from SnowFlake to postgreSQL. From SnowFlake, I was able to extract tables in CSV format using COPY. The COPY compresses the extract in gz format in aws s3.

Now the second step is to load these files in postgreSQL. I am planning to use postgreSQL COPY utility to ingest the data. However, I don't want to unzip the files. I would rather like to buffer the data directly from gz files and give the buffer file as input to the psycopg2 copy_from function.

Is there a way to parse gz files in AWS S3 using python? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/querying-data-without-servers-or-databases-using-amazon-s3-select/

Comment: @JonathanLeon thanks for your help. I will definitely check the url shared by you and update here. It'll take some time. But I will revert.